# "Don't Do A <NAME>"

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

What does this pattern mean?

> Don't Do A <NAME>

In which <NAME> is the name of a person being talked about?

Comment: Also note that this is sometimes phrased as "Pull a [name]" instead of "Do a [name]". They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Using names as a verb is a fairly recent development in English. While context is everything, it usually means something along the lines of:

> Don't do what [name] tends to do.

or

> Don't act like [name].

Here, the speaker is almost inventing a word based on the name.

Comment: In "do a [name]", the name is being used as a noun—note the article.